# turn off touch change slides on responsive carousel in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have responsive carousel from [here](http://basilio.github.io/responsiveCarousel/). When I'm on mobile version of my page I want carousel to change slides automatically and not change slide on finger move. Here I have my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/5vfpfp27/)

```
    $('.crsl-items').carousel({
  visible: 4,
  itemMargin: 30,
  autoRotate: 50000,
  itemMinWidth: 180
});
```

Comment: Your code change slides automatically ?

Comment: Yes it changes it automatically

Comment: Have you try to use `.width()` property to Jquery ? `if($( document ).width() < 500){ /*Your code change slides ...*/}`